# Explicit description of isomorphism when decomposing into irreps

Tags: rt.representation-theory, young-tableaux, schur-functors

I had a question which is slightly more general than [this one on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97203/question-about-decomposition-of-exterior-product): I am looking for an explicit description of the isomorphism
$\mathbb S_\nu(V\otimes W) \cong \bigoplus C_{\lambda\mu\nu} \mathbb S_\lambda V\otimes \mathbb S_\mu W$ from Exercise 6.11 in Fulton & Harris. [In said question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97203/question-about-decomposition-of-exterior-product), the author asks whether
$${\textstyle\bigwedge}^p(V\otimes W) \cong \bigoplus\nolimits_{\substack{\lambda\vdash p\\\\\ell(\lambda)\le n\\\\\lambda_1\le m }} \mathbb{S}_\lambda V \otimes \mathbb{S}_{\bar\lambda}W$$

is given by

$$ (v_1\otimes w_1)\wedge\ldots\wedge(v_p\otimes w_p) \longmapsto \sum\nolimits_{\substack{\lambda\vdash p\\\\\ell(\lambda)\le n\\\\\lambda_1\le m }} c_\lambda(v_1\otimes\ldots\otimes v_p) \otimes c_{\bar\lambda}(w_1\otimes\ldots\otimes w_p). $$

The answer is affirmative and in the comments it is said that this is due to Schur-Weyl duality. I frankly don't understand that argument: I do not see why the map is well-defined. One would have to show that simultaneous permutation of the $v_i$ and the $w_i$ with some $\pi\in S_p$ introduces a factor of $\mathrm{sgn}(\pi)$ on the right, and this is not at all clear to me. Can someone explain?

Comment: Good question; my bet is that the element of $\wedge^p\left(V\otimes W\right)$ has to be preprocessed by antisymmetrization when $p\geq 3$. An answer to this question is also likely to answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77948/an-isomorphism-of-2-schur-modules .

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to define the above map from $\bigotimes^p (V\otimes W)$, mapping $(v_1\otimes w_1)\otimes\cdots\otimes(v_p\otimes w_p)$ to the sum on the right. Then, you want to precompose that map with the inclusion $\bigwedge^p (V\otimes W)\hookrightarrow \bigotimes^p (V\otimes W)$ rather than showing it factors through the corresponding projection $\bigotimes^p (V\otimes W)\twoheadrightarrow \bigwedge^p (V\otimes W)$. Now if we proceed like that, it is no longer obvious that the map is surjective and we can not deduce from the Cauchy formula that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, which is why I said "bet" and not "answer" ;) .

Comment: Fair enough! =D It boils down to the same question, I suppose.