# The symmetric power of a tensor product

Tags: rt.representation-theory, tensor-products, schur-functors

In the representation theory, if $S^{\lambda}(V)$ is the irreductible representation of $\text{GL}(V)$ associated to a partition $\lambda \vdash n$ (in perticular, $S^n(V)$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ symmetric power of $V$), we have the following rule:

$$S^n(V \otimes W) \cong \bigoplus_{\lambda \vdash n} S^{\lambda}(V) \otimes S^{\lambda}(W) $$

The only proof (in fact, sketch of proof) that I have found is in the book of Fulton and Harris, but it uses module theory and functoriality of the construction $S^{\lambda}$, something that I don't want to use in my text. Does anyone know a reference for a proof that uses only the language of Young symmetrizers, Schur duality, or those kind of "more explicit" theories?

**EDIT** I'm looking for an explicit way to decompose an element

$$ \cfrac{1}{n!} \displaystyle \sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n} v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes ... \otimes v_{\sigma(n)} \otimes w_{\sigma(1)} \otimes ... \otimes w_{\sigma(n)}$$

of $S^n(V \otimes W)$ as a sum of elements

$$\left( \cfrac{1}{n!} \displaystyle \sum_{\sigma \in c_{\lambda}} v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes ... \otimes v_{\sigma(n)} \right) \bigotimes \left( \cfrac{1}{n!} \displaystyle \sum_{\sigma \in c_{\lambda}} w_{\sigma(1)} \otimes ... \otimes w_{\sigma(n)} \right)$$

of $S^{\lambda}(V) \otimes S^{\lambda}(W)$ for each $\lambda \vdash n$, where $c_{\lambda}$ is the set of the terms (with sign) of the Young symmetrizer. So, I would like to prove that

$$\cfrac{1}{n!} \displaystyle \sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n} v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes ... \otimes v_{\sigma(n)} \otimes w_{\sigma(1)} \otimes ... \otimes w_{\sigma(n)} = \\ \left( \cfrac{1}{n!} \displaystyle \sum_{\sigma \in c_{\lambda}} v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes ... \otimes v_{\sigma(n)} \right) \bigotimes \left( \cfrac{1}{n!} \displaystyle \sum_{\sigma \in c_{\lambda}} w_{\sigma(1)} \otimes ... \otimes w_{\sigma(n)} \right)$$

by term cancellation. I have done it for $n = 2, 3$, but is it too much to hope for a general expression?

**EDIT 2** After more researches, and by the question [Question about decomposition of exterior product](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97203/question-about-decomposition-of-exterior-product) , I think my question can be answer if I proove that the following map is an isomorphism:

$$ \cfrac{1}{n!} \displaystyle \sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n} ( v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes w_{\sigma(1)} ) \otimes ... \otimes ( v_{\sigma(n)} \otimes w_{\sigma(n)} ) \mapsto \\ \left( \left( v_1 \otimes ... \otimes v_n \right) \cdot c_{\lambda} \right) \bigotimes \left( \left( w_1 \otimes ... \otimes w_n \right) \cdot c_{\lambda} \right)$$

How can I do this?

Comment: It is quite easy to prove using symmetric functions. Would this be of interest to you?

Comment: The best proof I know uses multiplicity-freeness and an explicit description of the ${\rm GL}(V)\times {\rm GL}(W)$ highest weight vectors in the algebra of polynomial functions on $V\otimes W$ using elementary linear algebra. One reference is R.Howe's Schur's lectures, but I believe Procesi's book on Lie groups also has a nice exposition.

Comment: Tose two ideas are great, and if I don't find what I'm looking for, I'll probably take one of these. To be more explicit, I'm looking for an explicit way to decompose an element $\displaystyle \sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n} v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes ... \otimes v_{\sigma(n)} \otimes w_{\sigma(1)} \otimes ... \otimes w_{\sigma(n)}$ of $S^n(V \otimes W)$ as a sum of elements of $S^{\lambda}(V) \otimes S^{\lambda}(W)$ for each $\lambda \vdash n$. I have done it for $n = 2, 3$, but can I hope a general expression of this form?

Comment: I think the standard combinatorial proof is to apply the RSK correspondence.

Comment: See e.g. the section on the Wikipedia page mentioning the application to the Cauchy formula.